# Not able to display Report Data in LWC - Lightning page

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lightning, html, reports-api

I want to display report's data in created LWC page so that I can use the Report for further desired processing. Have followed [ReportManager Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_reports_reportmanager.htm) and am able to display Total Rows Count , Report URL (Link) , Columns but as a linear List , Rows but as a linear List too.

Also able to get the JSON output of getDataCells() , but I don't think that would be traversed to display data at frontend in HTML file. The commented code in the HTML file contains my trial & error code while trying to display JSON Data or attempting to connect controller class , js and html code to display rows and columns from ReportManager API into lightning page , but I am not able to get an expected output having  full table containing report data.

Report Data displayed with the help of table tags  `<tr>,<td>` or even DataTable would give me some logic to proceed with something if anyone could help with this.

Expected Result : Rows and Columns Data to be displayed in the form of a table same as how the actual Report is displayed in Salesforce.

Below are the Controller , JS , HTML files :

**ReportGenerator.cls**

```
public with sharing class ReportGenerator {

    public static List<String> getColsData( ID reportId ){
        List <String> colsList = new List<String>();
        // Run the report immediately
        Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
        for (String colName : results.getReportMetadata().getDetailColumns()) {
            colsList.add(results.getReportExtendedMetadata().getDetailColumnInfo().get(colName).getLabel());
           
       }
       return colsList;
    }


    public static List<String> getRowsData( ID reportId ){
        List <String> rowsList = new List<String>();
        // Run the report immediately
        Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
        Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factWithDetails = (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails) results.getFactMap().get('T!T');
        for (Reports.ReportDetailRow row : factWithDetails.getRows()) {
            for (Reports.ReportDataCell cell : row.getDataCells()) {
                rowsList.add(cell.getLabel());   
            }
        }
        return rowsList;  
    }


    public static String getReportAsJSON(Id reportId){
        List <String> rowsList = new List<String>();
        // Run the report immediately
        Reports.reportResults results = Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, true);
        Reports.ReportFactWithDetails factWithDetails = (Reports.ReportFactWithDetails) results.getFactMap().get('T!T');
        for (Reports.ReportDetailRow row : factWithDetails.getRows()) {
            for (Reports.ReportDataCell cell : row.getDataCells()) {
                rowsList.add(cell.getLabel());   
            }
        }
        return JSON.serializePretty(rowsList);
    }

    public static String getURL( ID reportId ) {
       Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
       Reports.ReportMetadata reportMetadata = describe.getReportMetadata();
       String reportURL = '/lightning/r/Report/' + reportMetadata.getId()+'/view';
       return reportURL;    
    }


    public static Decimal getCount( ID reportId ) {
       Reports.ReportDescribeResult describe = Reports.ReportManager.describeReport(reportId);
       Reports.ReportMetadata reportMetadata = describe.getReportMetadata();
       Reports.ReportResults results =  Reports.ReportManager.runReport(reportId, reportMetadata);     
       Reports.ReportFactWithSummaries factDetails = (Reports.ReportFactWithSummaries) results.getFactMap().get('T!T');
       List<Reports.SummaryValue> summary = factDetails.getAggregates();
       Decimal count = (Decimal)summary[0].getValue() > 0 ? (Decimal)summary[0].getValue():0;
       return count;
    }
}
```

**ReportController.cls**

```
public with sharing class ReportController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Decimal getRowsCount(){
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = getReports();
        return ReportGenerator.getCount(
            reportMap.get('New_Opportunities_Report_iz4').Id
        );
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getReportURL() {
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = getReports();
        return ReportGenerator.getURL(
            reportMap.get('New_Opportunities_Report_iz4').Id
        );
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> getReportRowsData(){
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = getReports();
        return ReportGenerator.getRowsData(
            reportMap.get('New_Opportunities_Report_iz4').Id
        );
    }



    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> getReportColsData(){
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = getReports();
        return ReportGenerator.getColsData(
            reportMap.get('New_Opportunities_Report_iz4').Id
        );
    }


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getJSONData(){
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = getReports();
        return ReportGenerator.getReportAsJSON(
            reportMap.get('New_Opportunities_Report_iz4').Id
        );
    }


    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String,Report> getReports() {
        Map<String, Report> reportMap = new Map<String, Report>();
        List<Report> reportList = new List<Report>([
            SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM Report  WHERE DeveloperName IN ('New_Opportunities_Report_iz4')
        ]);
        if (!reportList.isEmpty()) {
            for (Report r: reportLst) {
                reportMap.put(r.DeveloperName,r);
            }
        }
        return reportMap;
    }
}
```

**reportCard.js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import getJSONData from '@salesforce/apex/ReportController.getJSONData';
import getRowsCount from '@salesforce/apex/ReportController.getRowsCount';
import getReportURL from '@salesforce/apex/ReportController.getReportURL';
import getReportRowsData from '@salesforce/apex/ReportController.getReportRowsData';
import getReportColsData from '@salesforce/apex/ReportController.getReportColsData';

export default class ReportCard extends LightningElement {
    @track rowsCount;
    @track reportURL;
    @track reportRows;
    @track reportCols;
    @track jsonData;
    
    connectedCallback() {
        this.getCount();
        this.getReportURL();
        this.getRows();
        this.getCols();
        this.getData();
    }

    getCount() {
        getRowsCount() 
            .then(result => {
                this.rowsCount = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.rowsCount = undefined;
            }); 
    }
  
    getReportURL() {
        getReportURL()
            .then(result => {
                this.error = undefined;
                this.reportURL = result;
            }) 
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error
                this.reportURL = undefined;
            });
    }

    getRows() {
        getReportRowsData() 
            .then(result => {
                this.reportRows = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.reportRows = undefined;
            }); 
    }


    getCols() {
        getReportColsData() 
            .then(result => {
                this.reportCols = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.reportCols = undefined;
            }); 
    }



    
    getData() {
        getJSONData() 
            .then(result => {
                this.jsonData = result;
                console.log('JSON DATA ' + result);
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.jsonData = undefined;
            }); 
    }
}
```

**reportCard.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title={title}>            
        <template if:true={rowsCount}>
            <div class= "slds-var-m-left_medium">
                <h1> Total Records <br/> {rowsCount} </h1>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <a href={reportURL} target="_blank" class = "slds-text-heading_small">
                    View Report (This is Your Report)
                </a>

          

        <p class="slds-text-heading_small">Columns : {reportCols}</p>


                <p class="slds-text-heading_small">Rows : {reportRows}</p>

          
                <lightning-textarea name="displayJSON" readonly value={jsonData} label="Report JSON" ></lightning-textarea>


        <!-- Commented Code -->


          <!-- <table>
                    <template for:each={jsonData} for:item="cell">
                        <tr key={cell.dataCells}>
                            <td>{cell.dataCells.label}</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </template>   
                </table> -->


                <!-- <template for:each={jsonData} for:item="cell">
                    <option key={cell.dataCells.Id} value={cell.dataCells.Id}>{cell.dataCells.label}</option>
                </template> -->

                <!-- <template for:each={jsonData} for:item="cell">
                    <tr key={cell.dataCells.Id}>
                        <td>First row</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr key={cell.dataCells.Id}>
                        <td>Second row</td>
                    </tr>
                </template> -->

                 <!--  <lightning-card class="slds-text-title_bold"  title = "Report">
                    <div class="slds-var-p-around_medium lgc-bg" style="height: 300px;">
                        <lightning-datatable
                        key-field="Id"
                        columns={columns}>
                </lightning-datatable>
                    </div>
                </lightning-card>   -->

            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```